# Requirements for define within requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a process that merges all of my java script files into one big file, js_merged.js. Using require js, there are sections laid out like:

```
define([
    'oa-constants'
], function (OA_CONSTANTS) {
```

The merge process is built to eliminate the need for oa-constants.js.

However when I run, I get an error that oa-constants.js is missing.

Do java script files listed within `define` need to exist and be accessible? I understand that the `define` process makes it possible for that file to be referenced, so they need to exist?

Comment: thedepenedencies have to be fulfilled, even if they end up `undefined`.

Comment: the dependencies? @DanielA.White